# Azure Data Factory vs Synapse Workspace pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Can anyone explain to me what the difference is between Azure Synapse Workspace Pipelines and Azure Data Factory? There seem to be a lot of overlap or perhaps as if Data Factory is becoming part of Synapse Workspace pipelines?

I am still trying to get some clarity on this.
Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADF is built into Azure Synapse Workspace. It surfaces as Pipelines and Data Flows.